# Ruby recaptcha with multiple forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, recaptcha

We use the gem ruby-recaptcha.  It was easy to install and implement in almost every situation that needed it following the docs:
https://bitbucket.org/mml/ruby-recaptcha/wiki/Home
I've been stuck on one particular case and thought I'd ask if anyone else had solved this problem before I switched gems or tried hacking this one.

On cases where there are multiple forms in a single view (not ideal, i know) the helper method

```
get_captcha()
```

Looks like it will always add the captcha field to the first form.

Does anyone know a workaround to target a specific form or is it time to refactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an unrelated problem with the view.  *Foot in mouth*